# My remote ubuntu server is booting sporadically! What to do?

Tags: ubuntu

Can I look at any logs? Can I run any hardware check? All I have it a SSH terminal to connect to the server. I am hopping this is NOT a hardware problem. What can I do?

This is a physical desktop machine sitting in the other side of the country. I don't have physical access to the machine, but the person that has it says it is just turning off from time to time, something like every 15 minutes now. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's rebooting spontaneously, that's either a hardware problem or a very, very strange malware infection.  Hope as much as you want, but I'm betting it's dead.  Protip: don't use desktop hardware for a server you *need* to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Well check the syslog for errors and see what it gives, maybe there is somekind of hardware failure causing kernel panick. In your shell use :

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

It will show all messages dynamically being added to the tail.

Comment: That helped. It looks like I am booting after SQUID is being accessed. Maybe it was not a hardware problem but a SQUID problem? I purged Squid from my system. Let's see. Thx

Comment: Nope, it booted again. :-(